# Problem with checking Conditions in useEffect and React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Thank you for reading through my Issue and for your effort, to help me and give me guidance to my problem

I have this Problem. I'm using React Router Version 6. I a added ProtectedRoutes for logged in Users.
Thats all working. But in some views I check for example, if the user has an active subscription, and if not,
i redirect him to a CreateSubscription Page. I do this check on an model, which I got from an Context.

Problem is, that the View gets rendered, and shortly after that redirects to the correct view (fetch on render).
Can I somewhat check before render and then decide what to show ? Does the React Suspense API can manage such conditionals ?
Actually I do the check  like this.

```js
  const { workshop, token } = useWorkshopContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!workshop) {
      return;
    }
    //TODO: Get Redirects clustered to own Service and move to a hook before mounting to remove the show old view bevore routing. this is ugly!!!!
    if (workshop?.status === WORKSHOP_OLD_EXISTING_CUSTOMER) {
      navigate('/account/welcome');
    } else {
      if (workshop?.status !== WORKSHOP_ACTIVE) {
        navigate('/setup/subscription');
      }
    }
  }, [workshop]);
```

and on the Create Subscription Page I use This.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!workshop) {
      return;
    }
    if (workshop?.status === WORKSHOP_OLD_EXISTING_CUSTOMER) {
      navigate('/account/welcome');
    }

    if (workshop?.status === WORKSHOP_ACTIVE) {
      navigate('/app/dashboard');
    }
  }, [workshop]);
```

Routesfile looks like kinda:

```js
   <SentryRoutes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<RedirectToAuth0Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<RegistrationPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/signup/:workshop_id/:registration_form_key"
              element={<RegistrationPage />}
            />
            <Route path="setup" element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route
              path="setup"
              element={<ProtectedRoute component={PlainLoggedInUserWrapper} />}
            >
              <Route
                path="subscription"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={CreateSubscriptionPlanPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="verification"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={VerificationPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="polling"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={PollingPage} />}
              />
            </Route>

            <Route
              path={'account'}
              element={<ProtectedRoute component={WorkshopContextView} />}
            >
              <Route
                path="welcome"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={WelcomeExistingCustomerPage} />}
              />
            </Route>

            <Route
              path="app"
              element={<ProtectedRoute component={LoggedInUserAppShell} />}
            >
              <Route index element={<ProtectedRoute component={Dashboard} />} />
              <Route path="profile" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Profile} />} />
              <Route
                path="account/verification"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={AccountVerificationPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="account/update"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={AccountUpdateDataPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="account/subscription"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={ManageSubscriptionPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="vehicle"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={VehicleIdentificationPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="service-record/create"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={CreateServiceRecordPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="service-record/:id/update"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={UpdateServiceRecordPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="service-record/:id"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={ServiceRecordDetailsPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="request-service-record-history"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={ServiceHistoryPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="request-service-record-history/:id"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={ServiceHistoryPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="request-inspection-plan"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={InspectionPlanPage} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="service-activities"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={ActivitiesOverview} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="dashboard"
                element={<ProtectedRoute component={Dashboard} />}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route path="error" element={<ErrorPage />} />
            <Route path="404" element={<Page404 />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
          </SentryRoutes>
```

It uses an different layout,
than the upper View, so I couldn't to a conditional branching in the Layout component

In Vue router, they had the concept of before view render guards, which didn't work here in react router.
I tried to wrap it in descision wrapper components, I tried with passing callbacks (ended in errors with using useState in useEffect :)),
somewhat tried with xstate, tried react-location, but everything failed.
Does someone already solved this puzzle ? I'm pretty sure, because I think thats an quite common use case, but i failed on research.
Thanks in advance
regards Rainer

Comment: hm maybe put that in render?

Comment: Use some "loading" state for the initial render until you know what you want to render, or redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you ?

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

//...

function SomeComponent() {
  const { workshop, token } = useWorkshopContext()

  if (!workshop || !workshop.status) return <div>Loading...</div>

  if (workshop.status === WORKSHOP_OLD_EXISTING_CUSTOMER) return <Navigate to="/account/welcome" />

  if (workshop.status !== WORKSHOP_ACTIVE) return <Navigate to="/setup/subscription" />

  return <div>Hello world</div>
}
```

`useEffect` verison

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const { workshop, token } = useWorkshopContext()

function SomeComponent2() {
  const { workshop, token } = useWorkshopContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!workshop || !workshop.status) {
      return
    }

    if (workshop.status === WORKSHOP_OLD_EXISTING_CUSTOMER) {
      navigate('/account/welcome')
    } else {
      if (workshop.status !== WORKSHOP_ACTIVE) {
        navigate('/setup/subscription')
      }
    }
  }, [workshop])

  if (!workshop || !workshop.status) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return <div>Hello world</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `useInsertionEffect()` hook for this. Although the react team suggests this to use for the library authors but this can be of use here.

The `useInsertionEffect()` hook is fired before the DOM mutations are made.

Read more about it here:

- [React Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useinsertioneffect)
- [Know about the useInsertionEffect hook in React 18](https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/06/02/react-18-useinsertioneffect)

Note: This hook is only available since **React 18**.

Comment: Good, idea, didn't know that hook for now, thanks, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What was the effect of this hook?